# count values in each object of array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Sorry I've just changed this question :
I would like to know how many times I have THE WORD "orange" in my array. In this example "orange" > 4 times.

```
MyArray = [{
    fruit1: "Orange is blabla",
    fruit2: "Apple blabla",
    fruit3: "blabla Banana",
    color1: "ORANGE"
}, {
    fruit4: "blabla Orange",
    fruit5: "Apple",
    fruit6: "Banana",
    color2: "orange blabla"
}];

var newArr = MyArray.filter(function (item) {
    return _.values(item.xxx === "orange";
});
```

Comment: The length of newArr should work no? What's the issue?

Comment: I dont us underscore any more, so I am probably wrong.  SHould the values function take a function as  input or is it  an object?

Comment: it doesn't work because My property "item.xxx" is a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
MyArray = [{
    fruit1: "Orange is blabla",
    fruit2: "Apple blabla",
    fruit3: "blabla Banana",
    color1: "ORANGE"
}, {
    fruit4: "blabla Orange",
    fruit5: "Apple",
    fruit6: "Banana",
    color2: "orange blabla"
}];

var totalOrange = 0;

MyArray.map(function(item) {
  for (var key in item) {
    if (item[key].toLowerCase().indexOf('orange') >= 0) {
      totalOrange++;
    }
  }
});
console.log(totalOrange);
```

Comment: MyArray = [{
    fruit1: "Orange is blabla",
    fruit2: "Apple blabla",
    fruit3: "blabla Banana",
    color1: "ORANGE"
}, {
    fruit4: "blabla Orange",
    fruit5: "Apple",
    fruit6: "Banana",
    color2: "orange blabla"
}];

Comment: It's the same, just replace the MyArray.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way

```js
let MyArray = [{fruit1:"Orange", fruit2:"Apple", fruit3:"Banana", color1:"ORANGE"},{fruit4:"Orange", fruit5:"Apple", fruit6:"Banana", color2:"orange"}];

let result = MyArray.reduce((a, b) => {
    for(let key of Object.keys(b)){
        let re = /orange/gi;
        if(b[key].match(re) != null){
            a++;
        }
    }
    return a;
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: MyArray = [{
    fruit1: "Orange is blabla",
    fruit2: "Apple blabla",
    fruit3: "blabla Banana",
    color1: "ORANGE"
}, {
    fruit4: "blabla Orange",
    fruit5: "Apple",
    fruit6: "Banana",
    color2: "orange blabla"
}];

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this : -

```
const count =  MyArray.reduce((count,item)=>{
     Object.keys(item).forEach((val)=>{
       if(item[val].toLowerCase().indexOf('orange') != -1){
         count++;
       }
     })
     return count
    },0)
```

Comment: MyArray = [{ fruit1: "Orange is blabla", fruit2: "Apple blabla", fruit3: "blabla Banana", color1: "ORANGE" }, { fruit4: "blabla Orange", fruit5: "Apple", fruit6: "Banana", color2: "orange blabla" }]

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you can use spread syntax `...` and `Object.values` to do this.

```js
var MyArray = [{ fruit1: "Orange is blabla", fruit2: "Apple blabla", fruit3: "blabla Banana", color1: "ORANGE" }, { fruit4: "blabla Orange", fruit5: "Apple", fruit6: "Banana", color2: "orange blabla" }]

var count = [].concat(...MyArray.map(Object.values))
       .filter(e => e.toLowerCase().includes('orange'))
              .length;
              
console.log(count)
```

Comment: MyArray = [{ fruit1: "Orange is blabla", fruit2: "Apple blabla", fruit3: "blabla Banana", color1: "ORANGE" }, { fruit4: "blabla Orange", fruit5: "Apple", fruit6: "Banana", color2: "orange blabla" }]

Comment: @pifou Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this might work.
You could do it in one big loop to make it slightly faster, but this form in more readable imho.

```
const amountOfOranges = MyArray
    // transform each object into an array of its values
    .map( Object.values )
    // remove all values not named 'orange'
    .map( ary => ary.filter( value => value === 'orange' ) )
    // replace all arrays by their length
    .map( ary => ary.length )
    // sum the results
    .reduce( ( x, y ) => x + y, 0 );
```

Comment: MyArray = [{ fruit1: "Orange is blabla", fruit2: "Apple blabla", fruit3: "blabla Banana", color1: "ORANGE" }, { fruit4: "blabla Orange", fruit5: "Apple", fruit6: "Banana", color2: "orange blabla" }]

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyArray = [{fruit1:"Orange", fruit2:"Apple", fruit3:"Banana", color1:"ORANGE"},{fruit4:"Orange", fruit5:"Apple", fruit6:"Banana", color2:"orange"}];

var count = 0;
MyArray.map(function(item,index){
    Object.keys(item).map(function(key){
        if(item[key].toLowerCase().indexOf('orange') >= 0){
            count++;
        }
    });
});
console.log(count);
```

Comment: MyArray = [{ fruit1: "Orange is blabla", fruit2: "Apple blabla", fruit3: "blabla Banana", color1: "ORANGE" }, { fruit4: "blabla Orange", fruit5: "Apple", fruit6: "Banana", color2: "orange blabla" }]